# Why does mis-typed type hints work well in the code while it does not in debug console?

Tags: python, typing

What I tried to do was:

```
from typing import List
class Board():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.layout: List[List[int]] = [] 

t = Board(3, 4)
```

and I mistyped like this.

```
from typing import List
class Board():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.layout: list[list[int]] = [] # typo here

t = Board(3, 4)
```

I thought an error would occur because to my knowledge using types(list, tuple, dict, ...) as type hints is introduced in python 3.9 and I'm using 3.7.4. But on contrary no error occurred. Thought it's weird so I tried this:

```
a: list[int] = [0]
```

and...

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

which I expected at first when I made typo (List->list). I put a breakpoint in the original code:

```
from typing import List
class Board():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.layout: list[list[int]] = [] 
        ... # breakpoint here
        
t = Board(3, 4)
```

and in debug console...

```
self.layout: list[list[int]] = []
```

same error occurred.

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Question: If using 'list' as type hints is not allowed in my python version (3.7.4), why did my original code run without errors?

Thank you.

ps. maybe this is weirder...

```
from typing import List

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        a: list[int] = [0] # it works as a = [0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test()
    b: list[int] = [0] # TypeError occurs. Why?
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you refer to the debug console?

Comment: Type hints weren't introduced in 3.9, they've been there since 3.5: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/. It's the ability to use list instead of typing.List that's new: https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I mean Debug Console in vscode.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your comment. I'll check them out. Could you check the short snippet I've added? list[int] works in class definition while it does not outside. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean "weirder"? Or "works", for that matter - what's the point of or problem with either declaration? Please [edit] to give a single coherent [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry for my poor writing skills. Just edited last snippet. (This is my very first post in stackoverflow btw.)

Answer (score 0):

From [Runtime Effects of Type Annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations):

> Annotations for local variables will not be evaluated:
>
> ```
> def f():
>     x: NonexistentName  # No error.
> ```
>
> However, if it is at a module or class level, then the type *will* be
> evaluated:
>
> ```
> x: NonexistentName  # Error!
> class X:
>     var: NonexistentName  # Error!
> ```